# git/github workflow on rebasing remote branch

Tags: git, github

I have a remote branch where I pushed up changes from my local, then realize there was changes to master so i checkin to master run git pull then go back to my local branch and run git rebase master, however i cant push to my remote branch now because my local is ahead of it.

I just checked out a new branch from the local one and created a new one on github and issued a pull request for that.

Is that appropriate/acceptable? Is there something I could have done to rebase off my remote branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't rebase changes in from a branch that is already pushed to a remote (without modifying history).  This is because each commit is a log of the changes since its parent commit, meaning if the parent commit changes, so does the commit itself.  If you create a `feature` branch off of the `master` branch, and then more changes get added to the `master` branch, it would look like this:

```
master
 - a --- feature
           - 1
           - 2
 - b
 - c
```

Now if we try to `git pull --rebase origin master` onto `feature`, the two `feature` commits will have a different parent and different signature.

```
master
 - a
 - b
 - c --- feature
          - 1a
          - 2a
```

This is perfectly fine, and a great way to keep your local branches clean and up-to-date (avoiding "merge-commits").  However, if you already pushed your `feature` branch to a remote repo, then you would have to force and overwrite these 2 commits on `feature` (since their history has changed).  If anyone had done a `git fetch origin` and worked on top of `feature:2`, they would not be able to push their changes (since `feature:2` has been replaced by `feature:2a` and now the history is different.

---

Now for what is the appropriate workflow is kind of up for personal opinion, debate, and your specific environment.  For instance, if you are the **only** developer working on the remote or **no one** else has worked off of the `master` branch since you..you can do a `git push origin master -f` which will force overwrite the remote's `master` with your local copy.

How I suggest you going about this in the future, is making "feature" branches based off of `master` and keeping this history as clean as you can locally by using [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).  When you have a good chunk of clean commits that you are happy with, push them to the origin (any commits you've pushed to a remote repo, you do *not* want to rebase).

When you are happy with the branch, you can submit a pull request.  When you go about merging it in, I suggest you manually do it with `--squash` so that you can have a nice clean history on your `master` branch (it should read like a story).  This is how you would go about closing a pull request:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
git merge --squash origin/feature/branch
git commit
```

---

I know I kind of went in a roundabout answer there, if you have any specific things you want me to address please ask in the comments.  Here is some extra [reading](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/codebase/dev/git/clean-commits/) you may be interested in.